# How to combine 4 tables with joins and max

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a query I am trying to write in SQL Server 2008 to produce a row like this:

```
quoteID | dateEntered | insuredName | agentName | quoteType | status | noteDate | userType
```

I currently have:

```
SELECT
    t1.quoteID,
    t1.dateEntered,
    t1.insuredFirstName + ' ' + t1.insuredLastName as insuredName,
    t2.FirstName + ' ' + t2.LastName as agentName,
    t1.quoteType,
    t1.status,
    t3.noteDate
FROM
    quote_genericInformation t1

INNER JOIN tbl_agents t2
    ON t1.createUserID = t2.AgentNumber

INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT quoteID, MAX(dateEntered) as noteDate
        FROM quote_notes GROUP BY quoteID) t3
    ON t1.quoteid = t3.quoteid

ORDER BY t1.quoteID
```

This produces a result like:

```
quoteID | dateEntered | insuredName | agentName     | quoteType | status | noteDate
54      | 01/01/2000  | First Last  | First Last    | apptype   | open   | 01/01/2000
```

1. I need to add the usertype as another column, but when I add it, I start to get duplicates.
2. I need this to always show a row regardless if a quote_note exists for that quoteID
3. I need this to show the most recent usertype in the notes (based off the notedate)

Thank you!

Comment: WHat table is UserType in?  Can there be more than one UserType for a quote or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH note AS (
    SELECT quoteID
        , dateEntered as noteDate 
        , usertype 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quoteID ORDER BY dateEntered DESC) as row_num
    FROM quote_notes
)
SELECT
    t1.quoteID,
    t1.dateEntered,
    t1.insuredFirstName + ' ' + t1.insuredLastName as insuredName,
    t2.FirstName + ' ' + t2.LastName as agentName,
    t1.quoteType,
    t1.status,
    t3.noteDate,
    t3.usertype
FROM
    quote_genericInformation t1

INNER JOIN tbl_agents t2
    ON t1.createUserID = t2.AgentNumber
LEFT JOIN note t3
    ON t1.quoteid = t3.quoteid
    AND t3.row_num = 1
ORDER BY t1.quoteID
```

Comment: thank you for this, it worked like a charm. I have never used the with clause before, I will have to do some reading up on it.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 2: if you want a row returned always you should use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, rather than an INNER JOIN.
See Wikipedia for an explanation on join types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

As for the questions on usertype: we'll need more information about the database schema then. BTW I would advice to use consistent naming for your aliases  (like employees e and persons p, rather than t1, t2 etc). This makes the query much more readable IMHO.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I just stuck with t1 etc as I was fudging with the query.  I will update it soon to make it more readable.  I tried the outerjoin and it started to give rows without matches in both directions is seemed.

Comment: If it gives open matches from BOTH sides, you probably did a FULL OUTER JOIN? If you want to make sure it comes from one side only you use a LEFT OUTER JOIN (or RIGHT OUTER JOIN, but thats less usual.)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    t1.quoteID,
    t1.dateEntered,
    t1.insuredFirstName + t1.insuredLastName as InsuredName,
    t2.FirstName + t2.LastName as AgentName,
    t1.quoteType,
    t1.status,
    t3.noteDate,
    t3.usertype
FROM
    quote_genericInformation t1
INNER JOIN tbl_agents t2
    ON t1.createUserID = t2.AgentNumber
LEFT JOIN note t3
    ON t1.quoteid = t3.quoteid
    AND t3.row_num = 1
ORDER BY t3.noteDate desc